# SIne function in java and in matlab returns different values

Tags: java, matlab

I want to convert my matlab code  to java
In matlab I called `sin(1621*2*pi*0.0001)` and it returns   `0.7979`
now in JAVA I called `Math.sin(1621*2*Math.PI*0.0001)` and it returns `0.8513`

Why???

The problem was I use 0.0001 as java rounded but matlab does not round it

Comment: .8513 is the correct answer, see "http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%281621*2*PI*0.0001%29"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is 0.8513.

When I type it in Matlab I get 0.8513 as answer.

Maybe you should check in your code if you assign not a value to "pi" that is not equal to 3.1415...

Comment: Yeah you are right 
the problem is then I multiply by 0.0001 java round it but matlab answer was 9.0703e-05